# The precision exceeded the allowable maximum

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I have the following Insert from select statement, data from Linked Server ODBC.

But I get this error

> Msg 7354, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   The OLE DB provider "PervasiveOLEDB.11.0" for linked server "db29" supplied invalid metadata for column "Quantity". The precision exceeded the allowable maximum.

My code:

```
Insert DB1.dbo.WORKORDERS 
   ([WORK ORDER #],[QUANTITY],[CUSTOMER],[SO DATE],[SO NUMBER],[ASSY PN-S],[CUSTOMER PN],[SHIP VIA],[PROMISED DATE],[COMMENTS],[PO #],[WO Notes])
select 
  convert(varchar(10), next value for dbo.WorkOrderSequence ),
  x.Quantity,--
  x.Customer_Bill_Name,
  x.TransactionDate,
  x.Reference,
  x.ItemID,
  x.PartNumber,
  x.WhichShipVia,
  x.ShipByDate,
  x.Comment2,
  x.CustomerInvoiceNo,
  x.SalesDescription
from
  openquery
  ([db29],
    'select distinct           
       Customers.Customer_Bill_Name,
       JrnlHdr.TransactionDate,
    JrnlRow.Quantity,
       JrnlHdr.Reference, 
       LineItem.ItemID ,
       LineItem.PartNumber, 
       Customers.WhichShipVia, 
       JrnlHdr.ShipByDate, 
       JrnlHdr.Comment2,
       JrnlHdr.CustomerInvoiceNo, 
       LineItem.SalesDescription    
FROM   Customers
INNER JOIN JrnlHdr
ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = JrnlHdr.CustVendId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Address
ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = Address.CustomerRecordNumber
INNER JOIN JrnlRow
ON JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder
INNER JOIN LineItem 
ON JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber
WHERE  JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 11 AND JrnlHdr.TransactionDate = CURDATE()-1 
AND JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder  
AND JrnlHdr.CustVendId = Customers.CustomerRecordNumber 
AND JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber 
AND JrnlHdr.POSOisClosed = 0 ' 
)  as x
```

I tried to `cast quantity` as

```
 Cast(JrnlRow.Quantity as Decimal(38, 2)) as Quantity
```

but I get another error:

> > Msg 9803, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 Invalid data for type "numeric". The statement has been terminated.

i also

Comment: Can you connect to the linked server and get the data type (precision and scale) for db29.JrnlRow.Quantity? Also, the same for DB1.dbo.WorkOrders.Quantity?

Comment: Thanks Max SQL server DECIMAL (18,0) LINKED SERVER DATABASE `decimal(39,19)`

Comment: @MaxSzczurek when i try using  `Cast(JrnlRow.Quantity as Decimal(38, 2)) as Quantity,` works and when i try to retrieve another data i get `Column or parameter specified a column precision that is greater than the maximum precision of 38"`

Comment: sorry @MaxSzczurek linked server decimal(39,9) and Sql server max is decimal(38, )